# mixed java logging with slf4j, log4j and java.util.logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, java.util.logging

I'm running a web application in a Weblogic server (Im not realy familiar with ).
Via JVM args a log4j config is passed with log level DEBUG to the application.
In the log file I can also find some log entries of DEBUG level.

So far so good.
During debugging I found some calls to logger.debug() that are not in the log file.

private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActionCtr.class);

The method call is definitely hit but nothing is written to a file.

If I do a step into during debugging I see in the logger:
org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter(com.example.application.ActionCtr)
"java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern" -> "%h/java%u.log"

And this leads to some questions for me (as I can not change the running application):
1) how could it bee that it uses the application is using a mixed up log4j and java.util.logging
2) How could I determine what is used in what classes?
3) There is no %h/java%u.log (~/java*.log) so I've tried to provide a java.util.logging conform properties file, 
but this changed nothing - how an I determine where the running logger got its config from to configure it right?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) how could it be that it uses the application is using a mixed up log4j and java.util.logging

Any of those logging frameworks could be used by the application directly or a dependent library that the application is using.  It doesn't take too many dependencies to end up with a bunch of logging framework hitchhikers.

The [SLF4J manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) explains how that logging framework wrangles all of these other frameworks.  This why you are seeing the `org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter`.

> How could I determine what is used in what classes?

Assuming you mean direct usages you can use [Jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm) or [Javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

> how an I determine where the running logger got its config from to configure it right?

The [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) tool can access the JUL loggers at runtime.  It will also show you all of the system properties which may include paths to `logging.properties` files.

If the application is pragmatically configuring the logging in an non-standard way then one option would be to use the [`java.security.debug`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars003.html) using the `access` option.  Run the application under a security manager will all or all required permissions but then enable access tracing.